# Using Zappa as a conda user

Tags: flask, virtualenv, aws-lambda, conda, zappa

I am trying to create an API and looking to use Flask/AWS Lambda to do so.  As best as I can tell, [Zappa](https://www.gun.io/blog/serverless-microservices-with-zappa-and-flask) looks like the best (only?) deployment option.

The problem is that I use conda to manage my environments and Zappa does not currently have a version that can work in conda.  It requires virtualenv.

My questions are:

1. How are other conda users deploying Flask/AWS Lambda apps?
2. Can I run *both* virtualenv and conda on the same machine?  What are the risks/challenges?

Comment: Did you find any answer or userful information for this? i'm also a flask user, migrating apps to lambda, but managing envs with conda, so i'm interested.

Comment: I just set up virtualenv and use that in a different directory.  So far it works.

Comment: I'm trying out using `pip install zappa` right now, I'll get back to you once I see how it shakes out

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Fixed it by setting the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable and it worked.

Assuming you have a conda environment created as follows.

```sh
conda create -n zzz python=3.7
conda activate zzz
```

Before `zappa deploy` ensure you do the following.

```sh
(zzz) ➜ which python
/home/lokesh/miniconda3/envs/zzz/bin/python
# Remove the /bin/python and copy the rest
export VIRUTAL_ENV=/home/lokesh/miniconda3/envs/zzz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install it using conda:

```
conda install -c mathieu zappa
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the context of serving machine learning models on AWS Lambda?

If so, I wrote a library called [Thampi](https://medium.com/@rajiv.abraham/introducing-thampi-ec40a9b02a9d) which uploads your model and your conda environment to AWS Lambda and abstracts away the DevOps part of model serving. The caveat is that your conda requirements file has to be [manually written](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually).